# JBoss 7.1 logging is not working

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x

In my web application I am using apache logging log4j. When I was working jboss as 7.0, logging was working well.

But when i switched to Jboss 7.1 logging is not working. Can somebody let me know what has been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in 7.1 logging dependencies are added to each deployment. This works for most people, but if you're using your own log4j configuration this will not work for you in 7.1.1 and lower. You need to [exclude](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers log4j dependency.

**Note**: In 7.2.x this will just work and you can remove the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for reply James.
Here is my project structure. I have EAR project, under which I have created JPA,EJB and Web projects. In Web Project I have servlet context listener, which reads logger property file and initializes logger. 
Now I have created META-INF folder in my EAR project under EarContent. I have created jboss-deployment-structure.xml as mentioned above. But I am not getting information logged as I used to get in Jboss 7.0

Comment: Where did you add the jboss-deployment-structure.xml? In an EAR it should be in META-INF and you need to include log4j with your EAR/lib directory.

Comment: That's funny, the same comment "will just work" was made by JBoss developers when describing logging in 7.1 compared to 7.0.

Comment: That's because it will just work. The part that doesn't work as most would expect is when you don't use the defined logging configuration for the server and would like to use say a log4j.properties. In 7.2 you will be able to use a log4j.properties.

Comment: Thanks James, I have put the exclusion for each sub project of EAR and now it is working very well. I will try with JBoss 7.2.x also